# mem_fun fails, pthread and class ptr

Tags: c++, pthreads, std, member-functions

`pthread` takes in as its parameter `void *(*start_routine)(void* userPtr)`, I was hoping I can use `std::mem_fun` to solve my problem but I cant.

I would like to use the function `void * threadFunc()` and have the `userPtr` act as the class `(userPtr->threadFunc())`. Is there a function similar to `std::mem_func` that I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use a global function that calls your main thread function:

```
class MyThreadClass {
public:
  void main(); // Your real thread function
};

void thread_starter(void *arg) {
  reinterpret_cast<MyThreadClass*>(arg)->main();
}
```

Then, when you want to start the thread:

```
MyThreadClass *th = new MyThreadClass();
pthread_create(..., ..., &thread_starter, (void*)th);
```

On the other hand, if you don't really need to use pthreads manually, it might be a good idea to have a look at [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/thread.html), a good C++ thread library. There you get classes for threads, locks, mutexes and so on and can do multi-threading in a much more object-oriented way.

Comment: thread_started can also be a static function in MyThreadClass.

Comment: i would put extern "C" before the function, because pthread is a C function calling your stuff with C calling conventions. not sure what POSIX says about pthread though. maybe it requires it to be able to call C++ functions, but i highly doubt it.

Comment: i do something like this, a static function which calls the actual func with S prefixed to the functioname